# drupal_add_tabledrag dragging but not dropping

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to use the drupal_add_tabledrag in a form table, the dragging is added fine, but dropping is not working

```
    $entity_ids = range(10,20); // Loading dummy data

    $entities = entity_load('node', $entity_ids);
    $rows = array();

    foreach ($entities as $id => $entity) {
        $rows[$id] = array(
            'data' => array($entity->title),
            'class' => array('draggable', 'entity-weight'),
        );
    }

    $form['settings']['entities'] = array(
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => array(t('Title')),
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'entity_table')
    );

    $form['settings']['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Find entity'),
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'list_bean/autocomplete',
    );

    drupal_add_tabledrag('entity_table', 'order', 'self', 'entity-weight');

    return $form;
```

I can rearrange items using drag, but I cannot drop the item I drag, it sticks tot he cursor.